# XLConnect - readWorksheet with looping object

Tags: r, for-loop, xlconnect

I am using R Studio version 3.1.2 with XLConnect package to load, read and write multiple xlsx files. I can do this with duplicating and creating multiple objects but I am trying to do it using 1 object(all files in the same folder). please see examples
I can do this listing each file but want to do it using a loop

```
tstA <- loadWorkbook("\\\\FS01\\DEPARTMENTFOLDERS$\\tst\\2015\\Apr\\DeptA.xlsx")
tstB <- loadWorkbook("\\\\FS01\\DEPARTMENTFOLDERS$\\tst\\2015\\Apr\\DeptB.xlsx")
```

This is the way im trying to do it but get an error

```
dept <- c("DeptA","DeptB","DeptC")
for(dp in 1:length(dept)){
dept[dp] <- loadWorkbook("\\\\FS01\\DEPARTMENTFOLDERS$\\tst\\2015\\Apr\\",dept[dp],".xlsx")}
```

After this I want to use the readWorksheet function from XLConnect.

Apologies for the lame question but I am struggling to workout how best to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read all the files into a list in one operation as follows (adjust `pattern` and `sheet` as needed to get the files/sheets you want):

```
path = "\\\\FS01\\DEPARTMENTFOLDERS$\\tst\\2015\\Apr\\"

df.list = lapply(list.files(path, pattern="xlsx$"), function(i) {
  readWorksheetFromFile(paste0(path, i), sheet="YourSheetName")
})
```

If you want to combine all of the data frames into a single data frame, you can do this:

```
df = do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

Comment: When I try and use this I get the following errors      df.list = lapply(list.files(path), pattern="xlsx$"), function(i) {
Error: unexpected ',' in "df.list = lapply(list.files(path), pattern="xlsx$"),"
>   readWorksheetFromFile(paste0(path, i), sheet="TST")
Error in paste0(path, i) : object 'i' not found
> })
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Removed close parenthesis after `path`. Sorry about that. Try now.